# Google drive nodejs api returns deleted files

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, google-drive-api

I am using google drive api in my application. I have deleted the files from  google drive but still listfiles function returns those deleted files. Is there any solution to avoid this. Here is function of my API

```
router.post('/', Authorise, (req, res, next) => {
const auth = req.auth;
const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
drive.files.list({
    pageSize: 10,
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
}, (err, rslt) => {
    if(err){
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
    else{
        const files = rslt.data.files;
        if(files.length){
           res.status(200).json(files);
        }
        else{
            res.status(200).json({message: "No files found"})
        }
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check in the Metadata (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) the value of the boolean 'trashed'.

> Your problem may come from the difference between trashing and deleting:
>
> 1. trashing: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/trash <-
>      this is V2 API, I don't know if it works on v3
> 2. deleting: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete

edit: you could also run this:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/emptyTrash

Answer (score 3):

You could use this query:

```
await this.drive.files.list({
    q: 'trashed=false',
});
```

This way no trashed files from your folder are returned.

Comment: I'm doing this and it's still returning trashed files. I do have two conditions in my query, like this: q: "'" + folderID + "' in parents and trashed=false"

Comment: Docs for search query: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms

Answer (score 0):

Check the bin. You'll find deleted file there. That's why it's returning those files.